# Function.SendTransactionAsync() What value to pass to the param "value"?

Tags: nethereum

I am running a private blockchain node using geth as a client and nethereum to interface to a .net application.

In order to mine a function call I am currently using the function Function.SendTransactionAsync() like below:

```
var transactionHash = await newFunction.SendTransactionAsync(senderAddress, new HexBigInteger(700000), new HexBigInteger(1), parameter1, parameter2, parameter2);
```

The first HexBigInteger(700000) signifies the gas. 
What does the second HexBigInt refer to and how do I determine what value I should pass to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value parameter refers to the amount of Ether you want to send to the contract with that transaction.

When sending a transaction there are common parameters:

- To (the address where you sending the transaction, in this case, the contract address which is automatically set)
- From (the address from)
- Gas (the total amount of gas you want to spend, or gas limit)
- Gas Price (gas price)
- Value (the amount of ether (in Wei) you want to send, this can be to an account or a contract, in your scenario, you will be sending it to a contract. Your function in solidity should be able to access it using msg.value)
- Data (in your scenario, this is the function and parameters encoded)